# painless: wrong_method_type_exception: cannot convert MethodHandle(Strings)String to (Object)boolean

Tags: elasticsearch-painless

Sorry for the newbie question. I am trying a very simple script in painless, the goal is to narrow my output to get only error message fields (the final goal is to extract some information from error strings).
Can someone explain why I can only return a boolean from this query?

```
GET /myindex/_search
    {
      "query": {
        "script": {
          "script": {
            "lang": "painless",
            "source": """
              if(doc.containsKey('errormessages.keyword')){
                return doc['errormessages.keyword'].value;
              }
            """
          }
        }
      }
    }
```